# how to convert this turbo pascal code to turbo c++?

Tags: turbo-c, turbo-pascal

I learned turbo pascal eight months ago and now I am studying turbo c++, so far I only know how to translate writeln and readln to turbo c++. Could anyone help me translate this code from turbo pascal to turbo c++ please? Thank You :)

```
b:=3;c:=5;
while(b<c)do
begin
       x:=65;y:=10;
       z:=13;a:=13;
while(x>y)do
begin
         textcolor(0);textbackground(red);
         gotoxy(z,13);writeln('Û');
         gotoxy(a,13);writeln('  ');
    x:=x-1;
    a:=a+1;
    z:=z+1;
    delay(1000);
end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: I think you should first learn turbo c++ and then translate the code youself. I would also learn something less legacy than turbo c++.

Comment: @Tapani thank you for your suggestion. already done it :D